# Error mapping types. Mapping types: List`1 -> IList`1 System.Collections.Generic.List`1 -> System.Collections.Generic.IList`1

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, .net-7.0

Tech and Versions:

- Automapper 12.0.1
- AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 12.0.1
  -.net 7 (migration .net 2.1 to .net 7)

ConfiguraServices:

`services.AddAutoMapper(new Assembly[] { typeof(AutoMapperProfile).GetTypeInfo().Assembly });`

AutoMapperProfile.cs:

```
 CreateMap<Domain.Entities.User, User>()
     .ForMember(d => d.Photo, opt => opt.Ignore())
     .ForMember(d => d.PhotoSrc, opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest, destMember, context) => GetRelativePath(src.PhotoSrc)))
     .ForMember(d => d.Subscriptions, opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest, destMember, context) => context.Items.ContainsKey(Detailed) ? src.UserCourseSubscriptions : null))
     .ForMember(d => d.UserGroups, opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest, destMember, context) => src.UserVsUserGroups?.Select(s => s.UserGroup) ?? null))
     .ForMember(d => d.UserGroupsIds, opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest, destMember, context) => src.UserVsUserGroups?.Select(s => s.IdUserGroup) ?? null))
     .ForMember(d => d.UserPositions, opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest, destMember, context) => src.UserPositions));

  CreateMap<Domain.Entities.UserCourseSubscription, UserCourseSubscription>()
      .ForMember(d => d.CourseSessionPresences, opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest, destMember, context) => src.UserCourseSubscriptionPresences))
      .ForMember(d => d.CurrentCourseModule, opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest, destMember, context) => src.CurrentCourseModule != null ? src.CurrentCourseModule.Name : ""));

  CreateMap<Domain.Entities.UserCourseSubscriptionLog, UserCourseSubscriptionLog>()
           .ForMember(d => d.Test, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(src.Log) ? Common.Utilities.Tools.ConvertJsonStringToObject<CourseTest>(src.Log) : null));

  CreateMap<Domain.Entities.UserCourseSubscriptionPresence, UserCourseSubscriptionPresence>()
      .ForMember(d => d.User, opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest, destMember, context) => src.UserCourseSubscription?.User));
```

My DTO UserCourseSubscription:

```
  public class UserCourseSubscription : IDto
  {
      public int IdUserCourseSubscription { get; set; }
      public int IdUser { get; set; }
      public int IdCourse { get; set; }
      public int? IdCourseClass { get; set; }
      public int? IdCurrentCourseModule { get; set; }
      public string CurrentCourseModule { get; set; }
      public decimal? Classification { get; set; }
      public bool? CourseClassPresence { get; set; }
      public bool IsInitiated { get; set; }
      public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
      public bool IsActive { get; set; }
      public bool? IsApproved { get; set; }
      public int Minutes { get; set; }
      public long DateEndTicks => DateEnd.HasValue ? DateEnd.Value.Ticks : 0;
      [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateConverter))]
      public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
      [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
      public DateTime? DateStart { get; set; }
      [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
      public DateTime? DateEnd { get; set; }
      public User User { get; set; }
      public Course Course { get; set; }
      public CourseClass CourseClass { get; set; }
      public IList<UserCourseSubscriptionPresence> CourseSessionPresences { get; set; }

      public FormFile File { get; set; }
  }
```

And My Entity UserCourseSubscription:

```
 public class UserCourseSubscription : BaseEntity
 {
     public override bool IsNew() => IdUserCourseSubscription == 0;

     public int IdUserCourseSubscription { get; set; }

     public int Seconds { get; set; } = 0;
     public decimal? Classification { get; set; }
     public bool? IsApproved { get; set; }
     public DateTime? DateStart { get; set; }
     public DateTime? DateEnd { get; set; }

     public int IdUser { get; set; }
     public User User { get; set; }

     public int IdCourse { get; set; }
     public Course Course { get; set; }

     public int? IdCourseClass { get; set; }
     public CourseClass CourseClass { get; set; }

     public int? IdCurrentCourseModule { get; set; }
     public CourseModule CurrentCourseModule { get; set; }

     public bool? CourseClassPresence { get; set; }

     public int Minutes => (int)Math.Ceiling(Seconds / 60d);
     public bool IsInitiated => DateStart.HasValue;
     public bool IsCompleted => IsInitiated && DateEnd.HasValue;
     public bool IsActive => IsInitiated && !IsCompleted;

     public ICollection<UserCourseSubscriptionLog> UserCourseSubscriptionLogs { get; private set; } = new HashSet<UserCourseSubscriptionLog>();
     public ICollection<SurveyResponse> SurveyResponses { get; private set; } = new HashSet<SurveyResponse>();
     public ICollection<UserCourseSubscriptionPresence> UserCourseSubscriptionPresences { get; private set; } = new HashSet<UserCourseSubscriptionPresence>();

     public override IList<string> Validate()
     {
         var errors = new List<string>();

         if (!Common.Validations.Integers.IsValid(IdUserCourseSubscription, -1, null))
             errors.Add("Id inválido");
         if (!Common.Validations.Integers.IsValid(IdUser, 0, null))
             errors.Add("Id do utilizador inválido");
         if (!Common.Validations.Integers.IsValid(IdCourse, 0, null))
             errors.Add("Id do curso inválido");
         if (!Common.Validations.Integers.IsValid(Seconds, -1, null))
             errors.Add("segundos inválidos");
         if (Classification.HasValue && (Classification.Value < 0 || Classification.Value > 100))
             errors.Add("Classificação inválida");
         if (DateStart.HasValue && DateEnd.HasValue && DateStart.Value > DateEnd.Value)
             errors.Add("Data de inicio não pode ser superior à data de fim");
         if (DateStart.HasValue && DateEnd.HasValue && DateEnd.Value < DateStart.Value)
             errors.Add("Data de fim não pode ser inferior à data de inicio");

         return errors;
     }

 }
```

and when I try to authenticate i get the IList UserCourseSubscriptions for the autenticate user:

```
 // Load active subscriptions
  var subscriptions = await Mediator.Send(new GetSubscriptionsByIdUserQuery() { IdUser = user.IdUser });
  response.Subscriptions = _mapper.Map<IList<Domain.Dtos.UserCourseSubscription>>(subscriptions.Items);
```

The response.Subscriptions is a IList Subscriptions

When I debug, I have 21 subscriptions, BUT I got a error on this peace of code:
 `response.Subscriptions = _mapper.Map<IList<Domain.Dtos.UserCourseSubscription>>(subscriptions.Items);`

The error:

> Error mapping types. Mapping types: List`1 -> IList`1 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Application.Domain.Entities.UserCourseSubscription, Application.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[Application.Domain.Dtos.UserCourseSubscription, Application.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!.

- Tried changing IList to enumerable
- Make a reverse map
- map the UserCourseSubscription list in automapperProfile.cs

nothing works